# ValueAnimator туда-обратно

Tags: java, android

```
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.example, container, false);
Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
final int initialColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary);
final int finalColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.accent);
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
          float position = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
          int blended = blendColors(initialColor, finalColor, position);
          view.setBackgroundColor(blended);
          }
});
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
anim.reverse();
anim.setDuration(2000).start();
....
private int blendColors(int from, int to, float ratio) {
    final float inverseRatio = 1f - ratio;
    final float r = Color.red(to) * ratio + Color.red(from) * inverseRatio;
    final float g = Color.green(to) * ratio + Color.green(from) * inverseRatio;
    final float b = Color.blue(to) * ratio + Color.blue(from) * inverseRatio;
    return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
}//метод для того, чтобы использовались только initialColor и finalColor, а не все цвета 'радуги'
```

**Update:** Выложил полную функцию смены цвета `view`, вдруг кому-нить пригодится.

**P.S:** Подключите `compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'`, чтобы данная функция работала везде одинаково

Данная функция меняет плавно цвет `View` только в одну сторону из `initialColor` в `finalColor` и резко заново.

Как сделать так, чтобы он и обратно из `finalColor` в `initialColor` плавно менял?

Comment: Попробуйте `anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.REVERSE);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб неа, все также обрывисто и не бесконечно. И почему-то только три раза...

Comment: А если так: `anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Вот теперь отлично работает и красиво!!! Огромное Вам спасибо! Правда, странно то, что когда я писал `anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); anim.reverse();` , то так отлично не работает. Я так понимаю `reverse(); Animation.REVERSE;` - это разные вещи?

Comment: Да, это разные вещи. Первая показывает в каком направлении проиграть повторяющуюся анимацию при следующей итерации, а [второе](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#reverse()) - проигрывает анимацию в обратном порядке с момента, когда метод вызван. На повторения оно влиять, вроде, не должно. Т.е. действие одноразовое.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб понял, еще раз большое спасибо за помощь:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помимо установки бесконечного повторения анимации, можно установить тип повторения анимации в [REVERSE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#REVERSE)

```
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```